# Android - Match contacts with phone numbers from DataBase

Tags: php, android, mysql, contacts

I have a few little questions concerning contacts from Android.

I have a MySQL databases with users and their phone numbers and I want to retrieve the contacts from the contact list of the user phone which are matching with phone numbers in the database (-> users using the app in other words, a bit like whatsapp is doing when you see the contacts which are using the app..)

I was wondering how I could achieve that in an easy and rapid way.. I was guessing I could do as follow:

- asynctask class which is retrieving all the contact list with a cursor
- get the phone number of the current item in the cursor
- execute a sql query to see if contact exist .. with LIKE %phonenumber% (through php script)
- if exist, add the contact name to a list view

But this means that every times the user wants to see the list, there are a lot of requests that need to be done.

Does anyone have an idea of a better way to do it? An easier way ?

Comment: Retrieve all of the contacts for that user from MySQL, cache them and then compare the contacts on the phone with the contacts in your cached list?

Comment: But I don't know the contacts for that users from MySQL, that is the problem, I wanna know for a user which are the contacts in his phone who are already registered for the app (and so present with their phone number in database)